# Jetty + Apache ¿existe algún módulo?

Tags: apache, tomcat

tengo que realizar un trabajo en el que utilice el servidor Jetty.

En la asignatura hemos utilizado Tomcat y el objetivo del trabajo es que aprenda a instalar y administrar un servidor con la "misma finalidad" pero que sea otro.

El servidor Tomcat se puede integrar con Apache. Mi pregunta era si esto se podría hacer también con Jetty con algún módulo de Apache.

Comment: La integración de Apache con Tomcat se denomina AJP. Busca por "Jetty AJP".

Comment: Okey muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Hola me encontre con este [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Apache) hace un buen espero te sirva.

Como uso mucho  Nginx, yo lo que haría es ejecutar la aplicación y hacer un proxy desde apache para conectar con el servidor de Jetty, bueno eso seria la otra opción :-) , saludos.

Comment: Okey gracias, se que existe un módulo de apache general para hacer de proxy, pero como Tomcat tiene uno propio era x si jetty también, gracias :)